# How the GPU process non-graphic data in parallel?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

As the introduction of programmable shaders in graphic pipeline enabled GPGPU concept which makes use of GPU as a general processing engine suited for parallel data.

However, as far as I know, because GPU is still used for graphic processing a lot compared to GPGPU, it makes use of lots of fixed graphic pipeline stages that cannot be programmed.

If my understanding is correct, when one data is processed by the GPU regardless of the type of data (graphic or general), it should be processed through the fixed graphic pipeline which includes programmable stages and non-programmable fixed stages.

Does that mean non-graphical processing should go through graphical processing stages even though it doesn't make use of it? Or can it bypass those fixed stages used for graphics? If one can explain how the GPU pipeline works for GPGPU I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:**
GPGPU completely bypasses the rendering pipeline, but the pipeline is still used today.

GPUs consist of two main parts (in relation to your question). The first one is the processing part, which consists of the memory, registers, warp units, dispatchers and streaming processors. The other part is a set of controllers, that are responsible for geometry processing and the graphics pipeline. Those controllers just issue commands for the Streaming Processors on how to process the data for each of the steps of the rendering pipeline, either hardwired or based on user supplied shaders. NVidia calls them "PolyMorph Engine", AMD "Geometric Processor".

Historically, some of those controllers were hardwired to do things a single way, so you could only programm the vertexshader, fragmentshader and pixelshader. The tesselation controller e.g. was hardwired on the GPU and not user programmable. As demands grew, more and more of those controllers became user-programmable and today most of them are completely programmable ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_pipeline#Shader)).

In the beginning days of GPGPU, the only way to do computing was to hack the available shaders by using a texture with your input data on a full-screen face to calculate the result and then read the rendered image back ([See slide 26 on this introduction](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15418-s18/www/lectures/06_gpuarch.pdf)).

With CUDA, NVidia allowed users not only to program the shaders/polymorph Engine, but also directly interact with the Streaming processors and execute code on those (See slide 31 & 32).

This does not mean, that the graphics pipeline became obsolete, but now there is a way to completely bypass it and directly run code on the GPU processors. Nvidia has a nice explanation on how the pipeline works today, where you can also see both the PolyMorph Engine and the Streaming Processors [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/life-triangle-nvidias-logical-pipeline).

The Graphics pipeline still helps the dev by offloading repetitive and more complicated parts of the process, like managing the memory, managing warps, passing data and all that stuff. Theoretically you could probably write your own pipeline directly on the StreamingProcessors using CUDA and then render the result, but it would be tedious. Just how writing a GPGPU-Code using Shaders would be tedious.

Comment: This answer is exactly what I was looking for. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Although old GPUs have pipelines hardcoded in the chip, modern GPU itself is just a large ASIC that can compute vectorized data at stupid fast speed. It is human who defines what it can do. So the render pipeline is defined in the graphics library like OpenGL, not in GPU. Thus, GPU does not care what it is computing, as long as it is vectorized data, it can do all the computation needed and give you a result.

Comment: Does it mean modern GPU doesn't have any specialized hardware components dedicated to graphic acceleration? And all the library function makes use of general GPU instruction to build up complex function for processing graphics?

Comment: Right. Modern GPUs have Unified Shader, so programmers can use software to adjust all of the aspects they want. In old GPUs, the render pipelines only have a fixed number of shaders with some switches to set some functions on and off, so programmers need to put a lot of effort to render a good graphic with these limited resources. Now programmers can put their own light models in GPU and even separate computations on different shaders since they all defined by software. For scientific computations the principle is the same.

Comment: Not entirely right. Modern GPUs still have a pipeline, NVidia calls it "PolyMorph Engine" and AMD "Geometric Processor".